# MySQL Error with straightforward polymorphic association in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have 4 models, `Application` , `Accommodation`, `Invoice` and `InvoiceItem`

`Invoice`, `Application` and `Accommodation` all hasMany `InvoiceItem`

`InvoiceItem` belongsTo `Application`, `Accommodation` and `Invoice`

The purpose of all this is so that the line items of an `Invoice` (which come from the `InvoiceItem` model) can be associated with either an `Accommodation` or an `Application` via the `InvoiceItem.foreign_id` depending on whether `InvoiceItem.class` is set as `Accommodation` or `Application`

From what I understand, this is known as a polymorphic association.

Unfortunately, when I do a `$this->Invoice->find('all');` with recursive set to 3 (or set to -1 with the appropriate fields specified in containable) I get this MySQL error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 
'InvoiceItem.class' in 'where clause'

SQL Query: SELECT `Application`.`id`, `Application`.`name`, 
`Application`.`created`, `Application`.`updated` FROM `applications` 
AS `Application` WHERE `Application`.`id` = 3786 AND 
`InvoiceItem`.`class` = 'Application'
```

I don't understand why Cake would try to add `InvoiceItem.class` as a condition without creating a join for the `InvoiceItem` model.

Here are my models (note: I've cut down the number of fields in each for readability -- the `Application` and `Accommodation` models share very few similar fields in reality):

**Accommodation Model**

```
CREATE TABLE `accommodations` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

<?php 
class Accommodation extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Accommodation';
    var $hasMany = array(
        'InvoiceItem' => array(  
            'className' => 'InvoiceItem',
            'foreignKey' => 'foreign_id',
            'conditions' => array('InvoiceItem.class' => 'Accommodation'),
        )
    );
}
?>
```

**Application Model**

```
CREATE TABLE `applications` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

<?php 
class Application extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Application';
    var $hasMany = array(
        'InvoiceItem' => array(  
            'className' => 'InvoiceItem',
            'foreignKey' => 'foreign_id',
            'conditions' => array('InvoiceItem.class' => 'Application'),
        )
    );
}
?>
```

**InvoiceItem model**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoice_items` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `class` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `foreign_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

<?php 
class InvoiceItem extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'InvoiceItem';   
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Accommodation' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'foreign_id',
            'conditions' => array('InvoiceItem.class' => 'Accommodation')
        ),
        'Application' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'foreign_id',
            'conditions' => array('InvoiceItem.class' => 'Application')
        ),
        'Invoice' => array(
            'className' => 'Invoice',
            'foreignKey' => 'invoice_id',
        ),
    );
}
?>
```

**Invoice model**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoices` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

<?php 
class Invoice extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Invoice';   
    var $hasMany = array(
        'InvoiceItem' => array(
            'className' => 'InvoiceItem'
            'foreignKey' => 'invoice_id'
        )
    );
}
?>
```

I'm using CakePHP 2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

class InvoiceItem extends AppModel,and bind no belongsTo.

```
class InvoiceItem extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'InvoiceItem';   
    var $belongsTo = null
}
```

you can assign a suitable belongsTo to InvoiceItem at Runtime depend on content

```
$this->InvoiceItem->bindModel(array( 'belongsTo' => array(...) ) )
```